# how to prove the convergence of fixed point iteration algorithm

Tags: algorithms, convergence-divergence, recursive-algorithms, absolute-convergence

Please refer to the below algorithm:

[image]

Above two steps can be rewritten as,
\begin{equation}
x(k+1)=\arccos\bigg( -\frac{1}{2(Dr^{\frac {|\sin(2x(k)+\theta)|}{M\sin x(k)\sqrt{A+2B\cos(2x(k)+\theta)}}}+1)} \bigg)  \nonumber
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_{k+1}=f(x_{k})
\end{equation}

The work I did was above equations can be written as $x_{k+1}=f(x_{k})$ If,

1) $f'(n) \neq 0$, then the sequence  converges linearly to the fixed point $n$.

2)  $f'(n) = 0$, then the sequence converges at least quadratically to the fixed  point $n$.

But unfortunately first derivative is a messy equation and hard to prove

so any idea to prove the convergence of the algorithm?

Comment: @user44197 $\pi/2 \leq x(i) \leq 3\pi/2$

Comment: The statements 1) and 2) are valid only if you already know that the sequence converges.

Comment: Even with computing $f'$, one would possibly need some restrictions on $A,B,\ldots$. I assume you have at least $D>0$, $|B|<\frac12A$ as precondiitons.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how do you say that

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini is that possible to show the solutions of $x$ or $y$ is in converging sequence?

Comment: The problem statement itself is confused.  Variable $r$ is called an input, and is used in the formula for updating $x$, but $r$ is then referred to as the fixed point of something, presumably the iteration $x_{k+1} = f(x_k)$.  Complaining that the "first derivative is a messy equation" must be seen in the light of not clearly defining $f(x)$.

Comment: @hardmath inputs are constants and given in the problem. $x$ and $y$ are the varaibles.

Comment: @Harry:  What are we to make of "converges... to the fixed point $r$"?

Comment: @hardmath If we substitute the $y(i)$ value to second equation we can have $x(i+1)=f(x(i))$. That also indeed a messy equation

Comment: @hardmath please refers the question again. I did some modification, hope you can understand now. thanks

Comment: @hardmath now, is that clear to you?

Comment: @Harry:  I've asked you about your claim that $r$ is "the fixed point" of your iteration, in addition to stating that $r$ is an input.

Comment: @hardmath Sorry for the confusion. I have changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know which quadrant for $\arccos$?

Clearly the iterative function maps $[-\pi,\pi]$ into itself. So you should be able to establish the existence of the fixed point by Brouwer's fixed point theorem. Beyond that you need some proof of contraction. Your formula is a mess, so no idea how you will do it.

Comment: $\pi/2 \leq x(i) \leq 3\pi/2$

Comment: @Harry In that case by the nature of arccos we have $\frac\pi2\le x(i)\le\pi$ for $i\ge 1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen will that be helpful to prove the convergence?

Comment: @user44197  Brouwer's fixed point theorem can't apply in here